# Combobox event not firing

Tags: excel, vba, events, combobox, dropdown

I have a combobox (drop down list) that is populated with the names of all the sheets in the workbook. When I select one of them, it activates the selected sheet.

This was working until I copied it in another workbook and did some changes.

Here's the code I use to populate the combobox (which still works):

```
Sub fillAllCombos()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If ws.Name <> PVTSHEET Then Call fillCombobox(ws.Name)
    Next
End Sub

Sub fillCombobox(wsName As String)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim oCmbBox As Object
    
    Set oCmbBox = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(wsName).Shapes("cmbSheet")
    oCmbBox.ControlFormat.RemoveAllItems
    
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        oCmbBox.ControlFormat.AddItem ws.Name
    Next
End Sub
```

Here's how I capture the event:

```
Sub CmbSheet_Change()
    Dim oCmbBox As Object
    
    Set oCmbBox = ActiveSheet.Shapes("cmbSheet")
    With oCmbBox.ControlFormat
        If .Value <> "" Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(.Value).Activate
            .ListIndex = 0
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

The event-capture macros are in the sheet where the combobox is located.

In my search for answers I have also tried `CmbSheet_Click()`but same result.

I've named the combobox as in the image:
[image]

**Edit: `Application.EnableEvents = True`

Comment: Does `CmbSheet` appear in the left hand dropdown at the top of the main code window in the VB Editor when you are viewing the worksheet code module? I suspect not.

Comment: In the immediate window, type `?application.EnableEvents` and ensure that it returns `True`

Comment: Rory, you're right, it doesn't appear, but it also didn't appear in the previous working sheet. But I don't mind trying, is there anything I can do to add it there?

Ron, yes, I forgot to add that I also tested for this. Events are enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as if you have a `Form Control` Combobox. You can assign any parameter-less public sub to it, but you have to do this assignment manually. Just right-click on the control and select "Assign Macro...".

It's different for an `ActiveX Control` where the assignment is done via its name.

Comment: Thomas! You're right! I had actually tested for this but I must have done it from the wrong sheet. I had forgotten to assign the macro to the combobox...

Well, there go 5 hours of my life. Thank you so much guys!